# Ubuntu GUI after uninstalling GDM and x windows system

Tags: ubuntu, gui, x-server, gdm3

I read here about the difference between GUI,display manager, windows manager and desktop environments:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/411147/what-is-the-relationship-between-unity-gnome-gnome-3-compiz-metacity-and-li

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and removed both `gdm3` and `xserver-xorg` packages using:

```
apt purge -y xserver-xorg
apt purge -y gdm3
```

I still have GUI, different than `gdm3`. I expected to have no GUI after uninstalling these packages.

Why it happens?

#### edit

It turns out that after uninstalling both gdm3 and x windows system I got the lxde GUI.

1. Is it possible to "delete" GUI entirely?
2. Is it ok to delete the LXDE Desktop Environment or it will affect my system regarding non-GUI related staff I'm not aware of?

Thanks